# No errors on http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart but "ReferenceError:$ is not defined" if I run it from my computer (Notepad++)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am just starting to learn JQuery and found an example that could be useful for what I am doing (droppable, draggable, clone etc). It works perfectly OK on the website:

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

but somehow it gives me a "ReferenceError:$ is not defined" if I run it from my computer by using Notepad++.

I found a lot of discussions regarding this topic and a lot of useful and brilliant links, e.g. :

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.ca/2013/02/referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined.html

http://ryanrahlf.com/knockout-js-why-we-use-self-or-how-to-fix-referenceerror-xyz-is-not-defined/

but it is still a puzzle for me.

I would appreciate your feedback.

Thank you,
Russ

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` library? Are there multiple jQuery references?

Comment: Looks like if you are not loading jQuery properly. Using a local server is a point too.

Answer (score 2):

To run this sample from local computer, you need to replace these 4 tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

using full urls in href (with http schema):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/droppable/resources/demos/style.css">
```

otherwise it will attempt to include jquery from your local filesystem, i.e. will use file:: schema

Comment: actually, this is described as case 3 in link you found http://jquery-howto.blogspot.ca/2013/02/referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined.html